# Are questions looking for help to find data on topic?

Tags: discussion

There are some questions<sup><sub>[1](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2098/where-can-i-find-a-gwas-data-set-about-genotypes-and-phenotypes-for-zebrafish-an), [2](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2022/where-can-i-find-a-database-that-has-phenotype-information-together-with-associa?noredirect=1&lq=1)</sub></sup> about finding data suitable for an experiment or validate a method.

Are those question on topic?

I was going to post a new one but then I thought that it might be too broad.

Aside, I thought that a specific tag [find-data](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-data) would be appropriate to those questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I vote "definitely yes". Finding good datasets to learn from, to mine, to use to teach, or for many other things can be a complete nightmare. While the odds aren't terribly high that someone will be able to reply with, "here's an optimal dataset for <insert incredibly obscure topic>", if one can't ask here, then where can one?

For the record, I consider databases to be included in this, even though they'll often be comprised of information from multiple distinct datasets (this may be a distinction without a difference).